# Effectively grouping in SAS

Tags: sas

```
State   Zones   Climate BirdA   BirdB   BirdC   BirdD
NC  A   Hot 3   10  1   0
NC  A   Hot 0   1   0   1
CA  B   Neutral 4   11  1   0
CA  B   Neutral 0   1   0   1 
CO  C   Cold    5   0   1   0
CO  C   Cold    0   1   0   1
```

Above is example of data i have and i have to produce 3 reports as shown below. My question is, what is most effective way to write SAS Code when you have to create report with same metrics--here BirdA to BirdD but grouped by different variables--Here State, Zones and Climate. Will combination of array and Macro work here?. Appreciate your help.

**Report 1**
States  BirdA   BirdB   BirdC   BirdD
NC  3   11  1   1
CA  4   11  1   1
CO  5   11  1   1

**Report 2**
States  Zones   BirdA   BirdB   BirdC   BirdD
NC  A   3   11  1   1
CA  B   4   11  1   1
CO  C   5   11  1   1

**Report 3**
States  Zones   Climate BirdA   BirdB   BirdC   BirdD
NC  A   Hot 3   11  1   1
CA  B   Neutral 4   11  1   1
CO  C   Cold    5   11  1   1

Comment: Your 3 reports are identical

Comment: Hi Peter, yes reports are identical but groupings are different. First report is grouped by state, second with Zones and third with climate etc.. So I was trying to figure out what's the best possible solution when groupings are different but data under analysis is same. Is there a way to use SAS arrays and macros for grouping. thank you

Comment: You can print whichever variables you want with a PRINT command, so the groupings are the same, just the number of variables printed is different

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the same repeated process over and over (in this case different cuts of the same data) I'd use a macro to build up the outputted reports.

Then you'll just need to pass in the variables to "group by"

See this example:

```
data birds;
input state $ zones $ Climate $ bird_a bird_b bird_c bird_d;
cards;
NC A Hot 3 10 1 0
NC A Hot 0 1 0 1
CA B Neutral 4 11 1 0
CA B Neutral 0 1 0 1
CO C Cold 5 0 1 0
CO C Cold 0 1 0 1
;
run;

%macro sumBirds (classby, varby, out);
proc summary data = birds nway;
    class &classby;
    var &varby;
    output out = &out (drop = _type_ _freq_) sum=;
run;
%mend;
%sumBirds(state, bird_a bird_b bird_c bird_d, report_1);
%sumBirds(state zones, bird_a bird_b bird_c bird_d, report_2);
%sumBirds(state zones climate, bird_a bird_b bird_c bird_d, report_3);
```